# Sharing Data of File between many Controllers with Different Pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am Trying to share my File between two Controllers. First of all i get my File with drag and drop then i tried to share it using `sessionStorage`.

```
 $window.sessionStorage.dataTransfer = angular.toJson(e.dataTransfer.files[0],false);
```

and get the file with with Code:

```
fileUpload = angular.fromJson($window.sessionStorage.dataTransfer);
```

however, it does not work and what i understanded from Documentation that session storage could just accept until maximum size of 10/Mb but i want it to be unlimited size . Second i tried to share the data of file with services it works but when i go to the other page i am loosing data. so how could i share the data of file between two Controllers with two pages? any suggestion ?

Comment: Are you using different angular app ? or you are reinitializing your services where you are loosing the data?

Comment: i am using different angular app

Comment: [File objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) are exotic objects that can not be converted to JSON strings. The lifetime of the File object is tied to the document in the window on which it was created. The File object is released when the document is unloaded.

Comment: The [FileReader.readAsText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) method can be used to read the contents as text. The [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) provides other methods to read the contents.

Comment: FileReader.readAsText would not help that much Cause i need to reconvert data of file from string to data and here there is bo method like Filewriter so there is no serialzing and deserializing

Comment: create a module with a service and inject that module in all the application and use that service to share the data between the apps.

Comment: i did it however,when i go to other page it mean load new link for other controller so i ill lose all info

Comment: You were routing between different application having different modules which have services specific to the modules that's why you were loosing the data in service.